# Can't pick up correct version. Pronounced or pronounces?

Tags: grammar

In the sentence "It pronounces like this" can I use it like this? 
I've heard a lot of "It pronounced" so which version if correct?
And also should I use an article with the word correct?
A correct version or just correct version?

Comment: Alex, you have two questions that are not related to each other, so you should create a new ELL Stack Exchange question for the second one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"A person **pronounces** the word" (active voice) and "the word **is pronounced** (passive voice) like..."

About your second question, it depends on your context.

> 1. **A correct version** of the article is online.
> 2. Download **the correct version** for your OS